# How do I bind an existing instance method in one class to another class?

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a limited form of dynamic mixin on a class, taking methods from a third-party library class and binding them to my class. But nothing I've tried has worked correctly. All examples I've seen elsewhere bind a unbound function to a class but, in my case, I need to bind an already bound method to a different class.

Some example code I've been working with, with my failed attempts included:

```
import types
import traceback

class Class1(object):
    output = 'class1'
    def method(self):
        print self.output

class Class2(object):
    output = 'class2'

try:
    Class2.method = types.MethodType( Class1.method, None, Class2 )
    class2 = Class2()
    class2.method()
except:
    traceback.print_exc() # TypeError: unbound method method() must be called with Class1 instance as first argument (got Class2 instance instead)

try:
    class1 = Class1()
    class2 = Class2()
    class2.method = types.MethodType( class1.method, class2, Class2 )
    class2.method()
except:
    traceback.print_exc() # TypeError: method() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

class1 = Class1()
class2 = Class2()
class2.method = class1.method.__get__( class2, Class2 )
class2.method() # outputs 'class1' not 'class2'
```

Is this possible? Am I doing something wrong? Is there another technique I haven't seen?

Comment: So, you have a class A(), and want to make available some methods from a third-party class B() on it?

Comment: @rob-cowie yes, that is it. Dynamically, so I can't add it as a parent class.

Comment: The most common solutions would be to a) subclass Class1, or b) to wrap Class1 by passing an instance of it when you initialise Class2. Is there a good reason why you can't do either of these?

Comment: @katrielalex, no they're not. That's why I'm asking for an explanation of why they can't be used. It'll help to understand what the requirements are. Modifying the mro seems nifty, but unwise unless there is a good reason.

Comment: @Rob I am writing unit tests for a Google App Engine application and to get them to work I need to do some sys.path magic. And I want to include some useful functions from the Django unit test library into my custom unit test. But I can't use Django until after the unit test is set up. In other words, I can't import the class I want to use until the unit tests are being run, by which time it's too late to change the class definition the ways you suggest.

Comment: NP. If modifying `__bases__` works for you, then that's cool.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add it as a parent class dynamically, by modifying `YourClass.__bases__`:

```
>>> class Base: pass
>>> class Foo(Base): pass
>>> class Bar(Base): attr = True
>>> Foo.__bases__ = (Bar,) + Foo.__bases__
>>> Foo.attr
True
```

Alternatively, get the bound method object and extract the original function, then attach that as an attribute of your original class:

```
YourClass.method = OtherClass.bound_method.im_func
```

<sub>EDIT: you modify `__bases__` not `__mro__`. Oops.</sub>

Comment: Trying to modify the **__mro__** directly doesn't work, apparently it's a read-only attribute. And modifying it using **mro()** is also too early in the process. But, **im_func** is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I like the usage of `im_func`.

Comment: Huh. I could have sworn that I used the modifying-an-mro trick not too long ago. Oh well.

Comment: @Shane: I've remembered what I was thinking of: you can modify the `__bases__` attribute.

Comment: P.S. the reason both of the classes inherit from Base is a bug/issue in Python involving modifying the `__bases__` of classes inheriting _directly_ from `object`: http://bugs.python.org/issue672115

Answer (score 2):

Some modification in your code, hope It would work.

```
import types

class Class1(object):
  output = 'class1'
  def method(self):
    print self.output

class Class2(object):
  output = 'class2'

# you have to use im_func - bound or even unbound methods will fail
class1Method = Class1().method.im_func 

Class2.method = types.MethodType(class1Method, Class2(), Class2)
Class2().method() # it will print 'class2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a metaclass that would allow you to dynamically assign parent classes by overriding `mro()` in a way that would allow you to call it later in execution?

---

In response to your recent comment: you could perhaps use a factory function to produce the classes desired *after* the unit tests begin execution. This might work well with the idea of utilizing a metaclass.

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a couple of comments. Please put comments in the comments section.